# How can I make a component smart enough to know about a function that could have come from one of many sources?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is a large React/Redux app.

I have an overlay `<div />` on my site that’s used for several things.

The most common use case: When opening a modal, it sits on the `z-index` between site content and the modal, covering the content. Standard stuff. We also have a few types of alerts/messages that use the overlay in the same way.

Each of these interface items (modal, alert, message) that use the overlay require their own set of cleanup functions when they’re closed, and those functions depend on what was (or wasn’t) entered into their UI.

When closing a modal *from inside of the modal* (using the “x” or cancel button), it’s easy to know what those cleanup functions are because we’re performing the action from *inside of the modal*.

But, when closing the modal by clicking on the overlay behind it, how do I know what to run to do the cleanup? That could be any combination of dozens of functions, so it isn’t feasible to consider a switch/case scenario or anything like it.

Is there a standard practice for storing a reference to a function? Or passing a cleanup function from one component to another? Or another approach altogether?

BTW: Both `<Modal />` and `<Overlay />` components exist side-by-side in the `<App />` component, but other components that may use the `<Overlay />` do not.

Appreciate any tips I can get.

Comment: Can you move the cleanup functions into a commonly named method, and then handle the close event when you click the overlay, and trigger that method?  Then it doesn't matter what's on the screen - it just cleans up irregardless.

Comment: I _could_, but each component that uses the overlay has a different set of cleanup functions. I don’t think those should exist anywhere but with those components, should they.

Comment: So create a function called `cleanup()` (or something) that exists in the modal and calls the modal cleanup methods, one in the alert that calls the alert cleanup methods, and one in the message that calls the message cleanup methods.  Then you just call `cleanup()` when the overlay is clicked.

Comment: That’s a great idea. Funny… I was just adding something like that as an answer in case nobody else did, and in hopes that it wasn’t silly.

Comment: Wanna add a proper answer?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd put it in an answer that I'd consider worthy of being marked as such.  I think it should stay a comment and maybe you could post an example of your cleanup method as the answer, for anyone who stumbles in here with a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I’m adding an answer in case my plan miraculously turns out to be a good one.

1. Add a `handleCleanup` function to every component that will use the overlay.
2. Expose that function by adding a `ref` callback when rendering. Use a callback so that you only set the ref when the component is visible:

   ```
   ref={ (theModal) => {
       this.focusedWindow = modalIsVisible ? theModal : undefined; }
   }
   ```
3. When tapping the overlay, check to see if the ref is available. If it is, run the cleanup function:

   ```
   if (this.focusedWindow) this.focusedWindow.handleCleanup();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say without seeing your code, but I have a few thoughts:

- Why do you have to imperatively call a "cleanup" function? Why can't the modal/alert/message component clean itself up when hidden? Depending on how you hide it either use `componentWillUnmount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` when the prop that hides it is set.
- Since you say both `<Overlay>` and `<Alert><Modal><Message>` are siblings in `<App>` I would think `<App>` should know who's visible when, and can can handle all the cleanup. Or better yet, you can have a `<OverlayTrigger>` component that render a child and an `<Overlay>` and takes a `onCleanup` callback prop, then you have 3 instances of `<OverlayTrigger>` in your `<App>` with different cleanup handlers.
- Checkout the way [React Bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) (based on [React Overlays](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays)) has implemented overlays. They use [the "portal" method](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) to overlay components from any point in the component tree, then you don't have to deal with one top level single overlay, which is part of what's causing your problems. Component should be isolated.

I offer these possible alternatives because in general using refs and imperative API calls on components is discouraged in React.